# Why this array is wrong. Error: array bound is not an integer constant before ']' token

Tags: c++, arrays

error: array bound is not an integer constant before ']' token. How to make the variable be the length.

```
#include<iostream>
using namespace std;

int e;

int a()
{
  int b=3;
  return b;
}

e=a();

int d[e]={12,2,3};

int main()
{
  cout<<d[4]<<endl;
  return 0;
}
```

Comment: Please post code as text, not as an image.

Comment: aside from the error `d[4]` will yield undefined behaviour as you're indexing off the end of the array

Comment: short answer is: you cant. Anyhow it is completely unclear why you want the array size variable, when you initialize it with 3 elements

Comment: @tobi303 I need the user to input the size of the array.

Comment: it wont work if the user chooses size two. Lets say you manage somehow to get the variable size working, then still `d[2] = {12,2,3};` cannot work

Comment: @tobi303 don't mind these kind of details.This is only a test code. The main point is how can I let the user choose.

Comment: code is all about details and if I dont mind the details in your question there is almost nothing left ;)

Comment: you could use a `std::vector`

Answer (score 1):

An assignment such as `e=a();` cannot exist outside a function.

`int d[e];` is also not valid C++ as `e` needs to be a compile time evaluable constant expression.

So compilation fails with an albeit cryptic error.

Note that the behaviour of `d[4]` will be *undefined* due to your attempting to access an element outside the bounds of an array.

Comment: But How about i write int e=a();

Answer (score -2):

Try this:

```
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;

int a(){
int b = 3;
return b;
}

int main(){
int e;
e = a();
int d[e] = {12,2,3};
cout << d[0] << endl;
return 0;
}
```

As you can see, the size of the vector is just 3 (remember that in c++ the 0 counts as a position), so in this case you just can print 3 values, `d[0],d[1],d[2]`, remember that you can not assign a value outside of a function. Also if you plan to assign a global variable to array bound, it has to be constant. Like this: `const int e = 3;`, hope it helps.

Comment: This wouldn't work, as arrays have to have size known at compile-time.

Comment: This works, because it is a constant:                                                                        #include <iostream>

using namespace std;

const int MaxElementos = 6;

class S{
public:
        void muestra(int v[MaxElementos]){
                for(int i = 0; i < MaxElementos; ++i) {
                        v[i] = i;
                        cout << v[ i ] << endl;
                }
        }
};

int main()
{
    S Object;
    int v[MaxElementos];
    Object.muestra( v );

    return 0;
}

Comment: Yes, this one does work. The one in your answer doesn't.

Comment: Of course is not going to work! Because the function is changing the value and because of that is not a constant, in my answer I am just saying that if you want to use a global variable it has to be CONSTANT in order to use it with an array, which means that you can not change the value.